# Doctrine QueryBuilder HAVING expression

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

OK, so I'm rewriting some code, using Doctrine ORM (2.5).

The old code creates a query that has something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM couples INNER JOIN individuals ON (couples.id = individuals.couple_id)
GROUP BY couples.id
HAVING SUM(individuals.date_of_birth <= '1976-01-01') > 0
```

I have no clue how to implement this best using the Doctrine QueryBuilder.  This is a very simplified example, the real query is much longer and has a few HAVING clauses, all of which use `SUM(some_condition) > 0` to ensure that only Couples that contain a matching Individual will be retrieved.

I can add having clauses in Doctrine using `$queryBuilder->having()`, but I cannot do so using the `SUM()` function.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is nothing stopping you from using `sum` together with `having`:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('couple, individual')
    ...
    ->having('sum(individual.date_of_birth) > 0');
```

The `sum()` function of the query builder, actually takes in two arguments and returns a mathematical expression which is not what you're after.

When you use `sum` on a field like in the example above, that's actually the aggregating function.

Another thing to keep in mind in your case is that, according to the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html), every `having()` call overrides all previously set having conditions.
So if you want to use multiple of these, use `andHaving` and `orHaving`.

I hope this explains it.